# Captured image is not get added in gallery in oreo

Tags: android, image, android-8.0-oreo

I am referring this [android-image-picker](https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker) third party library to pick multiple images from gallery and camera. I have downloaded this sample code. I am using `Nougat` and `Oreo`. It's working fine in nougat. In `Oreo`, I observed a problem that, Captured images are not added in gallery instantly as it is showing in all other lower OS. Can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Do you request permission in the runtime to WRITE your pictures to the storage?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking the image send a broadcast with the path of clicked image in order to display the image in gallery.

```
private static void refreshGallery(String mCurrentPhotoPath, Context 
                                    context) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```